# template member use in advanced

Tags: c++, templates

i   read some code and see below definition:

you do need to see the code, it's just a code segment.

What my question related is only i use **** tagged, (every time i bold the word, always do not take effect)

those similar usage , does it mean that:

```
template <class A>
class AA {
   functionBB(A::C c) {}
}
```

My question is:
Does this mean that when the author define such a template, he know hw will always use the template with some specific class he know must have class member C?

```
  template<class **QueryDataT**>
    class BasicRoutingInterface : boost::noncopyable{
    protected:
        QueryDataT & _queryData;
    public:
        BasicRoutingInterface(QueryDataT & qd) : _queryData(qd) { }
        virtual ~BasicRoutingInterface(){ };

    inline void RoutingStep(typename **QueryDataT::QueryHeap** & _forwardHeap, typename QueryDataT::QueryHeap & _backwardHeap, NodeID *middle, int *_upperbound, const int edgeBasedOffset, const bool forwardDirection) const {
        const NodeID node = _forwardHeap.DeleteMin();
            const int distance = _forwardHeap.GetKey(node);

   ....
}
```

Comment: `tempalte` has to be `template` also your question is completely missing `My question is:`

Comment: This is why you must **absolutely pay attention to spelling.** "Defination" is only annoying as heck, but "tempalte" will cause your program not to compile (fortunately).

Comment: While I understand not everybody is fluent in English, this question is really confusingly worded (I didn't downvote, I think I understood it, but it surely is the reason for those downvotes). Please, take more time and try to clarify the question.

Comment: using `**` for bolding doesn't work in code segments since it's regular C++ syntax. E.g `int **ppi, **ppj;`

Comment: thanks , i will notice next times and work hard to heighten my english level and make my question cleary and not waste others' time. thx

Answer (score 0):

Template can refer to any members of the template parameter and any overloaded functions (outside the template parameter) expecting the template parameter as argument. These will be resolved when the template is instantiated.

Due to ambiguities in the C++ syntax, the template has to specify whether an identifier that depends on the template parameter is expected to refer to a type or not. So:

```
template <class A>
class AA {
    functionBB(A::C c) {}
}
```

is not going to compile under compliant compiler, because the syntax clearly expects `A::C` to be a type, but does not mark it as such. A `typename` keyword has to be used here

```
template <class A>
class AA {
    functionBB(typename A::C c) {}
}
```

(note, that `typename` is correctly used in the longer example above). Without `typename` keyword, it is expected to refer to value.

When template refers to members of the parameter type and it does not have them, one of two things can happen.

- If the member is not found in SFINAE context, the template definition is ignored. If there is another definition of the template or a non-template overload (in case of functions), they are used instead and no error occurs.
- In any other context, the compiler will emit an error.

A SFINAE context such that is part of the type signature of the template instance. That includes defaults of further template parameters, base type of a class template and argument and return types of a function template.

Comment: I think your SFINAE definition is incomplete. If a template refers to a member of a parameter type, and a given type doesn't have it, **and the template is instantiated for that type**, then the compiler emits an error at instantiation time. But this instantiation happens only after (partial) template specializations and function overloads have been considered.

Comment: @MSalters: You are right, but that does not really describe the set of contexts what will lead to SFINAE and which will not. If the _type_ of the template is not semantically correct, it will lead to SFINAE. If the body is not, it will lead to error.